# bootstrap Popover issue with placement:'auto'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popover plugin. and it is creating an issue. We are using placement:auto in js and in css we are using max-width:450px and width:auto in popover class. After applying this our popover is cutting off if our link is right hand side in the corner.

Please help me on this to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please explain the question correctly.@abhi.Preferably with code.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your JS file:

```
$(".popover-left").popover({placement:'left',trigger:'hover',delay:{show:500,hide:0}});
$(".popover-right").popover({placement:'right',trigger:'hover',delay:{show:500,hide:0}});
$(".popover-top").popover({placement:'top',trigger:'hover',delay:{show:500,hide:0}});
$(".popover-bottom").popover({placement:'bottom',trigger:'hover',delay:{show:500,hide:0}});
```

Seeing as I don't have your code, this is the best I can do for you.

I prefer not to use the `auto` option so I created different JS functions for them and use the desired class based on the placement and how I want the popover to behave.

I hope this helps.